# How to store a Dictionary in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, dictionary

Can some one demonstrate how I can save the values of a dictionary into a MySQL database?

```
public void Update()
{
           Dictionary<string,int> t = new Dictionary<string,int>();
for(int i = 0; i < t.Count;i++)
{
//What comes Here?
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First fix your iteration loop, second it is up to you to decide, eg:

```
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
conDataBase.Open();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in)
        {
            string constring = "..........";
            string Query = "insert into Tablename  values(@par1,@par2)";  
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@par1",entry.Key)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2",entry.Value)

           //Execute command
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```